# fgets() returning empty string

Tags: php, string

I am trying to read the first line in a text file, but the fgets() function does not seem to be doing the job. I have a hunch that it might be due to the way the new lines are done in the string, but I am not very experienced in the different ways that a new line can be denoted. I have an image from a website showing what the new lines are inputted as below as well as my code.

link(no rep for images): https://i.gyazo.com/373e217112edbfce272f82b2dae6b317.png

I have already tried changing the mode from w to w+ which I thought would fix the problem, but it did not. I also tried trimming the string using the trim()  function in php but that also did not work. I have verified that I am actually writing into the file as well.

Here is the code,

```
<?php
    $input = "def sum(numbers):
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        total += x
    return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))";

    $answerFile = fopen("/afs/cad.njit.edu/u/a/j/ajr74/public_html/answer.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file.");

    fwrite($answerFile, $input);
    $line = fgets($answerFile);

    print($line);

?>
```

I am expecting the output to be the first line of the file before the first CR LF tags, but I am getting an empty output instead.

Comment: What do you see when you directly view the file in a text editor? Does it exist?

Comment: Yeah when I view the file answer.txt it has the string in it.

Comment: Do you only want to read back a "single  line" i.e. def sum(numbers): ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the file pointer is at the end. To bring it back you can use [rewind](https://www.php.net/rewind) in between writing to your file and reading from it.

So

```
fwrite($answerFile, $input);
$line = fgets($answerFile);
```

Becomes

```
    fwrite($answerFile, $input);
    rewind($answerFile);
    $line = fgets($answerFile);
```

*Note*: that's aside from the fact that you already have the content. Normally you wouldn't really need to read form the file, you could just extract the first line from `$input`. But I guess that you're either just learning or planning to do this in two different points.

Comment: That's what I was missing :) the ole rewind.

Comment: Trying to extract the first line from input wasn't working for me so I tried putting it into a file.

Comment: @Leonidous thanks for accepting.. on a side note, if you still want to give getting the first line without reading it from the file a chance you could try to use something simple like `$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $input)`, which should get you an array with the lines from your `$input`, and after that you should find what you need on the first element, so on `$array[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

After performing a write, you would need to reset the pointer to read the contents back. Best way is to close it and open it for reading.

```
<?php
$input = "def sum(numbers):
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        total += x
    return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))";

//$file_name = "/afs/cad.njit.edu/u/a/j/ajr74/public_html/answer.txt";
$file_name = "./answer.txt";
echo "Write {$file_name} and Read back a line<br>";

$answerFileHandle = fopen($file_name, "w+") or die("Unable to open file.");
fwrite($answerFileHandle, $input);

// Required these two lines to close and re-open the file.
// Resets the pointer after the write operation above
fclose($answerFileHandle);
$answerFileHandle = fopen($file_name, "r") or die("Unable to open file.");

$line = fgets($answerFileHandle);
echo $line;
fclose($answerFileHandle);
```

Output is:

```
`Write ./answer.txt and Read back a line 
 def sum(numbers):`
```